# There was a problem rendering this document in storyboard visual studio mac

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

There was a problem rendering this document in storyboard visual studio mac.but same storyboard was opening in xcode perfectly but its not opening in visual studio. how can i solve this.

thanks in advance

Comment: Try to update your visual studio to the latest version.

Comment: i installed new version but still same problem, showing like this https://imgur.com/a/X4tZ3sA

Comment: What's your Xcode's version? And try [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/89193/error-when-openning-ios-designer.html) to see if it works.